# docker-compose keep container running after run entrypoint

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose

My *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    redis:
      container_name: redis
      image: redis:3.0
    app_prod:
      container_name: app_prod
      build:
        dockerfile: .docker/app/prod.Dockerfile
        context: ./../
      ports:
          - "8080:80"
      links:
        - mysql:mysql
        - redis:redis
      depends_on:
        - mysql
        - redis
      environment:
        PRODUCTION_MODE: 'true'
      entrypoint: .docker/app/sh/entry-point.sh
    mysql:
      image: mysql
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my-db'
      build:
        context: ./mysql # path to folder containing Dockerfile
```

My *.docker/app/sh/entry-point.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e # exit script if any command fails (non-zero value)
echo Waiting for redis service start...;

while ! nc -z redis 6379;
do
sleep 1;
done;

echo Waiting for mysql service start...;

while ! nc -z mysql 3306;
do
sleep 1;
done;
echo Connected!;

php www/index.php orm:schema-tool:update --force

exec "$@"
```

I am building by command:

`docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build`

All containers are built successfully but at the end is running **entrypoint** script of container *app_prod* (*.docker/app/sh/entry-point.sh*). Entry point script was processed successfully too but after execute entrypoint script is **app_prod** container stopped.

It is some way to keep container running?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Definitionally, no: once the entrypoint exits the container exits.

Your entrypoint is a shell script ending in `exec "$@"` (good!) which means that, after it successfully waits for its databases to be up, it will run whatever is passed in the `docker-compose.yml` as `command:`.  (Note that if you declare `entrypoint:` in `docker-compose.yml`, [it ignores a CMD in the Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint).)  So you just need a `command:` that starts your service and you should be set

```
entrypoint: .docker/app/sh/entry-point.sh
command: php-fpm
```